# Problema con usuario en identity ASP.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

Hola amigos tengo una duda con esto de `Identity`.

Ya tengo mi seguridad con ello, pero necesito saber es como puedo relacionar ese `id` de usuario o cual es la manera correcta de hacer esto.

**Explico más a detalle:**

- Tengo una `App`, la cual quiero para ir llevando mis gastos obvio cada usuario debe tener su propio usuario e ingresar sus propios gastos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es:

¿ingreso el `id` de la tabla que me genera `identity` `(AspNetUsers)` en mi tabla `GstGastos`? o ¿cual es la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Si tuvieran algún pequeño curso se los agradecería.

Saludos

Comment: Tu tabla UsrGastos debe desaparecer los datos que tiene ya estan incluidos en AspNetUsers. En tu Tabla AspNetRoles sustituye RoleId en lugar de Id, debes llevar una congruencia con tus tablas en cuanto a nombres e idioma, trata de evitar las abreviaturas a menos que sean muy necesarias ejemplo IdGst debe ser GastoId, DescripcionGst por solo Descripcion. Haz una prueba de datos usando una hoja excel asi tendras mas claridad que campos estas usando y para que te sirve.